# Is it possible to create property file during installation of msi?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I need to create property file during installation of my application.
Is it possible to do it?
Or only ini files could be create during installation?

Comment: What do you mean? A Java properties file?

Comment: @Tom Blodget Yes, java properties file. key=value. Or json file.